# Error 415 Unsupported Media Type while trying to http.post from a ionic 3 project to a java webservice

Tags: angular, http, jersey

I have a java backend project that uses JERSEY and a ionic 3 project for the front end. I can't get the post method to work, although the get method works fine.

this is the post method >

```
      @POST
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Path("/")
      public Response create(Oferta oferta) throws SQLException,                                    ClassNotFoundException{
    ofertaDAO dao = new ofertaDAO();
    dao.insert(oferta);
    return Response
        .status(200)
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT,      DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
        .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
        .entity(oferta)
        .build();

}
```

I've tried to do my post function at my ionic project in two different ways, this :

```
    postData(params){
    let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
     return this.http.post(this.api,params,{
     headers: headers
     }).map(
     (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
      );

       }
```

And this way >

```
          postData(params){           
          let headers = new Headers({'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
          return this.http.post(this.api,params,{
          headers: headers,
          method: 'POST'
          }).map(
          (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
          );

           }
```

The first way i get http 400 error, and the second way i get 415 error. What im missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a 415 error because the server expects application/json, and you set the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

You get a 400 because the data you're sending are not valid: the server expects some specific JSON structure and values, and you're sending something else. You should have an error message in the response telling what is wrong. Check what you're sending, and check what the structure of an Oferta is supposed to be.

Note that setting the content-type header to application/json is useless, since Angular does that for you when posting an object.

Comment: Yea you were right, had to set the ngModel names same as the oferta properties, working fine now! ty